# How many syllables are in "nights 'n' days"?

Tags: syllables

While I was trying to match the number of syllables in my poem, I could not be sure how many syllables these sentences below have.

*Count the nights and days spent together in spite*
*Count the nights 'n' days spent together in spite*

Do these both have 11 syllables? I think the second one has 10 syllables. Am I wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you pronounce "nights'n'days"? If the middle *'n'* is distinguishable, it's a syllable.

Comment: the "n" I think would be phonetically transcribed with a schwa and would therefore be syllabic.

Comment: *Nights ’n’ days* is just like *Days ’n’ nights*, the latter of which rhymes with *raison bites*, which clearly has three syllables, and so too must then they all.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabic_consonant

Comment: _n_ is a syllable, it's simply emphasized less than the full word _and_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nights 'n' days has three syllables. It is not a spondee.